# boost::interprocess - allocate_aligned in shared memory?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, memory-alignment, boost-interprocess

If I use `allocate_aligned` to allocate an aligned memory block within a chunk of shared memory, how do I then identify that same block in another process ? E.g.

```
managed_shared_memory managed_shm(open_or_create, "SharedMemory", 65536);
void *ptr = managed_shm.allocate_aligned(256, 16);
```

How do I then find `ptr` from within another process ?

For non-aligned allocations I just use `find_or_construct` and then obviously there is a name associated with the allocation which makes it possible to find the allocation from another process. However there doesn't seem to be any way to do aligned allocations with `find_or_construct` and evidently I must be missing some fundamental point as to how to identify anonymous allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features) included below.  This is applicable to pointers to memory returned allocate_aligned method as well as the vanilla allocate method.

```
//Process A obtains the offset of the address
managed_shared_memory::handle handle = 
   segment.get_handle_from_address(processA_address);

//Process A sends this address using any mechanism to process B

//Process B obtains the handle and transforms it again to an address
managed_shared_memory::handle handle = ...
void * processB_address = segment.get_address_from_handle(handle)
```

Comment: Ah thanks - the idea of sending an offset from one process to another hadn't occurred to me - I guess the handle could even go in a named allocation in shared memory.